# How to use a variable in dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable with the same name as a column in a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
b <- 5
```

I want to get the rows where `df$b == b`, but dplyr interprets this as `df$b == df$b`:

```
df %>% filter(b == b) # interpreted as df$b == df$b
#   a b
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6
```

If I change the variable name, it works:

```
B <- 5
df %>% filter(b == B) # interpreted as df$b == B
#   a b
# 1 2 5
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to tell `filter` that `b` refers to an outside variable.

Comment: this might help you file:///Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/dplyr/doc/nse.html

Comment: @MLavoie what is this? Better to provide [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

Comment: @Pascal. There was similar question a few days ago and I don't remember where it is. But it looks like the environment is important here and this link explain how dplyr's verbs can be used in a similar context. but I might not have understood the question, so if it's the case disregard my comment :)

Comment: @MLavoie  You misunderstand my comment. You provided a path to a local file, which only works for OSX users, not for Linux and Windows users. I simply provided the Internet version to the same file.

Comment: Typing `vignette("nse")` in the console is another option

Comment: This was the recent question here on [filter and nse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713002/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use the `get` function to fetch the value of the variable from the environment.

```
df %>% filter(b == get("b")) # Note the "" around b
```

Comment: This no longer works with `dplyr` 0.7.8. It returns all the rows.

Comment: Specifying the environment with `df %>% filter(b == get("b", envir = .env))` does still work (dplyr 0.8.3)

Answer (score 53):

Recently I have found this to be an elegant solution to this problem, although I'm just starting to wrap my head around how it works.

`df %>% filter(b == !!b)`

which is syntactic sugar for

`df %>% filter(b == UQ(b))`

A high-level sense of this is that the `UQ` (un-quote) operation causes its contents to be evaluated before the filter operation, so that it's not evaluated within the data.frame.

This is described in this [chapter of Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html), on 'quasi-quotation'. This chapter also includes a few solutions to similar problems related to non-standard evaluation (NSE).

Comment: I am confused by your caveat: I get now same result with `b == !!b` as `!!b == b`, while the latter is different from `!!(b == b)`. Maybe different versions ( I have dplyr 1 and rlang 0.4.7)? Can you confirm? Thanks!

Comment: This is a good point, thank you. This behavior changed in later versions of rlang. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

`rlang`, which is imported with `dplyr`, has the `.env` and `.data` pronouns for exactly this situation when you need to be explicit because of data-masking. To explicitly reference columns in your data frame use `.data` and to explicitly reference your environment use `.env`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(.data$b == .env$b) # b == .env$b works the same here

  a b
1 2 5
```

From the documentation:

> Note that .data is only a pronoun, it is not a real data frame. This means that you can't take its names or map a function over the contents of .data. Similarly, .env is not an actual R environment.

You do not necessarily need to use `.data$b` here because the evaluation searches the data frame for a column with that name *first* (as you found out).

Answer (score 8):

As a general solution, you can use the SE (standard evaluation) version of `filter`, which is `filter_`. In this case, things get a bit confusing because your are mixing a variable and an 'external' constant in a single expression. Here is how you do that with the `interp` function:

```
library(lazyeval)
df %>% filter_(interp(~ b == x, x = b))
```

If you would like to use more values in `b` you can write:

```
df %>% filter_(interp(~ b == x, .values = list(x = b)))
```

Comment: `filter_` is now deprecated.